# Javadoc tag @link with Doxygen : unable to resolve link

Tags: hyperlink, javadoc, doxygen

I documented with Javadoc and I appreciated a lot the integration with Eclipse as but I wanted to use Doxygen in order to add diagrams.

I use the tags {link foo} in several brief descriptions to link to standard Java classes and to my own classes.

Here is an SSCCE:

```
package org.foo.myproject;

import javax.swing.JList;

/**
 * This is a Javadoc line {@link JList}
 * 
 * @author theauthor
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
public class JavadocLinkFailedDemo {
}
```

I get the following error with Doxygen (1.8.4) : `Warning: unable to resolve link to JList for \link command` (I use a doxyfile template generated with doxygen.exe, edited for .java sources and specific input/ouput directories)

This is a similar problem with this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11991616/526840) but the solution of topic's author didn't work for me.

Thanks for your help in advance.

EDIT1:
I just tried to generate the Java API with doxygen to get the corresponding tag file. Then, I used this file with this demo project where I added a constructor using one parameter as a JList => The link is resolved only for this parameter, never with a link command.

EDIT2:
I finally succeed keeping this kind of signature: {@link ...}.
For my example, JList is resolved if you meet the following conditions:
 - Write the fully qualified name of the class file
 - Generate the documentation of the jdk with doxygen to generate a tag file and use this tag in your project

The final example code is:

```
package org.foo.myproject;

import javax.swing.JList;

/**
 * This is a Javadoc line with {@link javax.swing.JList}
 * 
 * @author theauthor
 * @version 1.0.0
 */
public class JavadocLinkFailedDemo {
    /**
     * This is a Javadoc line of the constructor with {@link javax.swing.JList}
     * 
     * @param aList
     *            The list
     */
    public JavadocLinkFailedDemo(JList aList) {
    }
}
```

The final result:
[image: http://s11.postimg.org/wgndev8hv/doxy_jdk.png]

However, it is nearly impossible to build a .chm help file because it takes a while to do this task and you get an very big file. But it is another problem...

Answer (score 0):

I havn't tried this, but I believe what you need is an escape character before you `@link`. This should look like `\@link` or `@@link`, but I would prefere the `\@link`.

Now I believe doxygen should be able to handle your javadoc comment correctly, however I'm not sure if this will work for JavaDoc, or if JavaDoc is now complaining. Also it may look strange in your doxygen documantation because there should show up a `@link JList}`, ... and I guess thats not exactly what you want either.

Comment: Sorry but I've misread this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11991616/526840). It worked also for me but I've many projects to update if I want to fix every link to Javadoc API. So I'm looking for a solution to link my project documentation to this external documentation.

Comment: I saw this [feature](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/external.html) but I understood that it works for external Doxygen documentation not for an offline Javadoc documentation (which is available in .zip archive format). I tried to run Doxygen over the src files of my jdk but I've got tons of errors...

Comment: ah okay, I believe I'm getting what your probelm is, you are using the @link as Javadoc comment and when you run doxygen it handels \link as a doxygen comment and gives you a lot of errors

Comment: Each command which start with a at-sign (@) is supposed to be supported. see this [link](http://www.stack.nl/~dimitri/doxygen/manual/commands.html). It seems that Doxygen failed with link command of any format when an external link is required

Comment: of course, but `@link` is a JavaDoc instruction that has a specified signature `{@link ...}` `@link` is also a doxygen instruction. So if you JavaDoc it is able to interpret your instruction. If you run doxygen it is not able to interpret the instruction, because it requires a `@endlink` directive to complete the instruction. So you need to distinguish between both commands.

Comment: +1 for solving it yourself, and now I finally understand what you tried to achieve :)